# Unable to Include a Remote Image in NextJS Image Component

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

Trying this for 2 days now followed all the steps mentioned in the docs but seems like it is not reading the config or something

**Error Page Shown**

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid src prop (https://images.pexels.com/photos/14397947/pexels-photo-14397947.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1) on `next/image`, hostname "images.pexels.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
```

**Component Used**

```
<Image 
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14397947/pexels-photo-14397947.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
        alt={props.team.name}
        width={props.width}
        height={props.height}
        placeholder="blur"
    />
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.pexels.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/photos/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I tried many things but doesnt seem to work

```
npm run dev               // tried restarting the server but no luck
npm run install:clean     // tried clean install doesnt work
npm update                // doesnt work
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

I tried different things and found the solution i was using
**Notus NextJS**
which had a slightly older version of nextjs so i ran

```
npm outdated
```

and updated the package.json and ran

```
npm run install:clean
```

Comment: Could You Please provide link to the repo or add all of your code and show us package.json file ?

Comment: use old way it will work``images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    domains: ['images.pexels.com'],
  },``